# Logtrail not displaying data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have swarm with ELK stack, with custom container of Kibana with Logtrail.
When I turn it on, I can see logs in Kibana but not in Logtrail plugin. I have always no events found message.

My config looks like (for testing purposes)

```
{
    "index_patterns" : [
        {
            "es": {
                "default_index": "logstash-*",
                "allow_url_parameter": false
            },
            "tail_interval_in_seconds": 5,
            "max_buckets": 500,
            "nested_objects" : false,
            "display_timezone": "local",
            "default_time_range_in_days" : 0,
            "max_hosts": 10,
            "display_timestamp_format": "MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
            "fields" : {
                "mapping" : {
                    "timestamp" : "@timestamp",
                    "display_timestamp" : "@timestamp",
                    "hostname" : "message",
                    "program": "message",
                    "message": "message"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My log entry visible in Kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2017.06.27",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVzrfuXhrXfjBRR51Pyo",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "source_host": "10.255.0.5",
    "level": 6,
    "created": "2017-06-27T13:31:01.373596557Z",
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
    "message": "Discovered 3 resources",
    "version": "1.1",
    "call_site": "onResourcesFound:76",
    "command": "java -cp classes:dependency/* Application",
    "tags": [
      "_dateparsefailure"
    ],
    "image_name": "xyz",
    "@timestamp": "2017-06-27T21:39:41.137Z",
    "container_name": "xyz",
    "service": "device-management",
    "host": "Docker-2",
    "@version": "1",
    "tag": "59858d7aa20d",
    "image_id": "sha256:acbccc5b39088ac1b2993e9e9dcd290e7cfa10499ef5eeca9f145d44ccc5571b",
    "container_id": "59858d7aa20dae4bc6220c4ff7366d7bef059d50213e852c3adab2eb8493af08",
    "timestamp": "17-06-27 21:39:41.137"
  },
  "fields": {
    "created": [
      1498570261373
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      1498599581137
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1498599581137
  ]
}
```

Where could be the problem please?

Comment: Did you sort this out? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: No. Still not solved, it's in waiting mode :)

Comment: Got it sorted out for me. I noticed that in kibana there was a tag on the log lines named something like grokfailedparsing. I then changed my grok filter to adapt to the logging which made them pop up in logtrail. Hence, my conclusion is that logtrail is more picky than the normal kibana logging.

Comment: I have grokfailedparsing there as well. But I use it, some log entires have it and some not. What do you mean that you adapter grok filter? All messages are now successfully parsed, what is the requirement for Logtrail? Thanks!

Comment: I messed around quite a bit with it and I don't actually remember exactly what I did to make it work, but I know that I configured the grok filter in the logstash conf file to match the incoming log format.

Comment: Could you please post here your grok configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this line in your JSON file anywhere:

```
 "message_format":"{{{syslog_message}}}"
```

You should be able to add fields to it using {fieldname} within the existing line.

Some reference pages:

[here](https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail/issues/131) and [here](https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail-config-examples/blob/master/syslog/logtrail.json).

At one point I had my own custom message_format setup, but can't find reference to the page where it showed me how to format it.

edit:

Also it looks like you need to map your fields properly. Below is my lost and found index in a json file:

```
{
  "index_patterns" : [
    {
      "es": {
        "default_index": "lnf-*",
        "allow_url_parameter": false
      },
      "tail_interval_in_seconds": 10,
      "es_index_time_offset_in_seconds": 0,
      "display_timezone": "local",
      "display_timestamp_format": "MMM DD HH:mm:ss",
      "max_buckets": 500,
      "default_time_range_in_days" : 0,
      "max_hosts": 100,
      "max_events_to_keep_in_viewer": 5000,
      "fields" : {
        "mapping" : {
            "timestamp" : "@timestamp",
            "display_timestamp" : "@timestamp",
            "hostname" : "logsource",
            "program": "program",
            "message": "message"
        },
        "message_format": "{{{message}}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice you have 'message' in each of the field mappings...